# Auto Insert new field into SP List  on page PostBack

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I've just created a new webpart. I'm a beginning on Sp Word. 
I built a new WP the get some data from textBox and put it  into a content list. 
But every time I do Refresh a new void item is inserted into the list. 
How can I control this post back?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a SharePoint problem, but a general Web programming problem. The answers to this article on stackoverflow has a couple of solutions: [Page Refresh Causes Duplicate POST in ASP.NET Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743580/page-refresh-causes-duplicate-post-in-asp-net-applications)